# R Markdown removing c vector

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

when I create a data frame like below

```r
m <- data_frame((most_characters$films)
```

I got this result (in markdown file)

```r
c(“The Empire Strikes Back”, “Attack of the Clones”)
```

How can I remove c in here

Comment: You need to assign a column name i.e. `data_frame(col1 = most_characters$films)`

Comment: factor is not working ;(

Comment: `data_frame` is a deprecated function, instead it would be `tibble(col1 = most_characters$films)`

Comment: @akrun it doesnt work unfortunately this two methods.

Comment: Can you please show the exact code that you are using to get the result with `c()` in markdown file?

Comment: @RonakShah                                                                                                          
 ###   2.Which character(s) did play in the Star Wars movies most?

```{r include=FALSE, comment='' }
(df<-select(starwars, name, films))
df$film_count <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(df) ){
  df$film_count[i] <- length(df$films[[i]])
}

(most_characters <- df[which.max(df$film_count),])
 m <- data_frame(most_characters$films)
```

Comment: @user978673 Please can you edit your post to include the code. The code included in comments is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact code

#### 2.Which character(s) did play in the Star Wars movies most?

```
{r include=FALSE} 
(df<-select(starwars, name, films))
df$film_count <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(df) ){
  df$film_count[i] <- length(df$films[[i]])
}

(most_characters <- df[which.max(df$film_count),])
 m <- data_frame(most_characters$films)
```